# Check every row for two expressions

Tags: bash

In my `CheckCodingGuidelines` script I want to check if there are still 'TunerParams' and 'CalcInternal' in the Textfile. If so it should be a negative result of the test.

What I have got so far:

```
while read line                                                                 
    do                   

        if [[ $line == *TunerParams* ]]                           
        then                                                                    
            DOCUMENTATION_TEST_A=1
        else
            DOCUMENTATION_TEST_A=0      

            fi

        done < $INPUT_FILE

        if [ $line === *CalcInternal* ]]
        then
            DOCUMENTATION_TEST_A=1
        else
            DOCUMENTATION_TEST_A=0
            fi




if [[ $DOCUMENTATION_TEST_A=0 ]];   
then                                       
    echo "error: Rule12: Still TunerParams and CalcInteral in Script                                   

fi
```

I know that I am probably making a complete and utter fool of myself but its the first day that I am dealing with bash.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net is your friend!

Comment: we all have to start from somewhere ;-). At least you're **trying** AND you're aiming in the right direction on a non-trival problem. Agree about shellcheck.net, but `awk` is designed to deal with this class of problems. Check out http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html for a good tutorial. Good luck.

Comment: the `done` line should be at the bottom after all your `if` testing. Look at shell `case` to simplify the syntax of this sort of testing. (`case` not available in all versions of `awk`). Also you probably want `[[ "str" ~= *match* ]]`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for all your motivational responses and the links but could you please just help me quickly this time since I have to finish this thing today and I ll be starting looking into it from now on and learn to do it myself please?